# Catalog URL Rewrites - Index Management - Stuck in Processing

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, reindex

Magento 1.9.3.1 - Catalog URL Rewrites - Index Management - Stuck in Processing.

I have had this happen in the past on earlier versions of Magento and I have been able to get one of the fixes already online to work (replace app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/URL.php in Local with patch / code fixes) - I also have the Index Optimization module installed.

Nothing is fixing it this time. I am on a shared server with limited direct server shell access. Also - there is no file in the var/locks folder.

Any and all help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have SSH access for your directory/project ?

Comment: I do not have SSH access

Comment: Do you have access of cpanel ?

Comment: yes I do have cpanel access

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK As you dont have SSH access and you cannot fire command directly,

so you can setup cron with your `cpanel`

just go to your cpanel and setup cron with near by time with below command

```
 php -f  /your_magento_dir/shell/indexer.php reindex
```

So choose your near time so cron run with in that time and your problem would solved.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. This worked. I'm not sure why my reindex.php script/file wouldn't do the same thing, and I have been super busy and super tired. So, right now, I'm just happy to have this solved.

Comment: @Classic you are always welcome :)

Comment: `php -f ./indexer.php -- reindex catalog_url` You can specify there at the end which `reindex` you want. Also, I think that `--` might be compulsory.

Comment: @CodeFinity if you don't specify then it will reindex all indexes

Comment: When I ran yesterday, it seemed to do all of the 'reindexing' anyway - not just for `category_url` - even though that took the longest and all the others were just a minute or so. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

Login to your mysql database through ssh and type "show processlist" and their comes an output simliar in the table and find the process id where their is continue execution of query related to core_url_rewrite. Once you get the process id you can kill this process using "kill id" (where id should replace with the process id).

Once successfully killing process id now refresh the indexmanagement page in the magento admin. you can see their is no indexing process which is stucked in Process. Now you can reindex it.

Comment: I do not have SSH access